# Firefox UI line "glitch"

Tags: html, css

I have a "small" issue on my website with Firefox. On Google Chrome and Safari it is working just fine.

What it should be (Chrome and Safari):

[image: correct design]

Issue on Firefox:

[image: issue on firefox]

```css
.headline {
  line-height: 1.5em;
  position: relative;
}

.headline:after {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 230px;
  margin: 5px 2%;
  border: 2px solid #64c800;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<h2><span class="headline">Contact</span></h2>
```

The expected result is that the green line should be below the header (in this case below "Contact".

Reproducible code:
Important forgotten note; I use Bootstrap 4 too.

```html
<style>
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin: 25px auto 5px auto;
    max-width: 820px;
    min-height: 600px;
    padding: 1px 0px 30px 0px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #603813;
    text-align: center;
}
.headline {
    line-height: 1.5em;
    position: relative;
}

.headline:after {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 230px;
    margin: 5px 2%;
    border: 2px solid #64c800;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
</style>

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h2><span class="headline">Contact</span></h2>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post an example where we can see the issue in Firefox. Currently the result in FF is exactly the same as in Chrome (first picture)

Comment: Result looks as desired in FF 60 on Debian

Comment: @cloned and @domsson; I just added an example code block. Thanks for mentioning!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you don't define a vertical position (`top` or `bottom`) for your line, so the browser kinda just does anything.

Try adding

```
.headline:after {
  top: 100%;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0p7948Lx/2/

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce your issue in Firefox 60.8 on Debian. However, here is a somewhat simplified approach that works without `position`, `transform` and `border`. I find it a little more elegant.

Maybe it fixes the issue as well?

```css
h2 {
  width: 230px;
  text-align: center;
}

.headline {
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

.headline:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 8px;
  margin-top: 1em;
  background: #64c800;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<h2><span class="headline">Contact</span></h2>
```

Comment: If I do this, and add a width of 230px, the line is not centered below the text.

Comment: @StevenVerheyen actually, that's very simple to do with the above approach. Just add the `width` to the enclosing `h2` element. See updated code.